# Python3 Numpy array concatenation with stride?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have some arrays

```
x = np.empty(3)
y = np.empty(3)

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = float(i)
    y[i] = float(i + 3)

print(x, y)
```

Output ~ `[0., 1., 2.], [3., 4., 5.]`

I would like to be able to get this instead

```
[0., 3., 1., 4., 2., 5.]
```

How can I do that?

I tried `zip`, but that appears to create an iterable class, not a new instance of the objects passed to it.

I tried `np.concatenate()`, but it didn't appear to have a "stride" option, which is along the lines of what I'm probably looking for. (No luck with a search however)

Comment: @a_guest yes it did thanks

Comment: Then please mark as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.stack((x, y), axis=1).ravel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip`:

```py
np.ravel(list(zip(x,y)))
```

Output:

```py
[0. 3. 1. 4. 2. 5.]
```

You can unpack `zip` by putting it in `list` constructor then flatten it with `numpy.ravel`.

Answer (score 0):

Making  your arrays without iteration:

```
In [157]: x = np.arange(3); y = np.arange(3, 6)                                 
In [158]: x, y                                                                  
Out[158]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]))
```

We can join them into a 2d array with

```
In [159]: np.array((x,y))         # np.vstack also works                                              
Out[159]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

We can then `ravel` or flatten the 2d array.  By specifying `fortran` order, we get the interleaving that you want:

```
In [160]: np.array((x,y)).ravel(order='F')                                      
Out[160]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5])
```

With the default 'c' order:

```
In [161]: np.array((x,y)).ravel()                                               
Out[161]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Another way is to stack them as columns:

```
In [162]: np.stack((x,y),axis=1)                                                
Out[162]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
In [163]: np.stack((x,y),axis=1).ravel()                                        
Out[163]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5])
```

Making a list from the zip:

```
In [164]: list(zip(x,y))                                                        
Out[164]: [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

This list is group; there are ways of flattening such a such list.  But we could also use `extend` to join the tuples to a list:

```
In [165]: alist = []                                                            
In [166]: for i,j in zip(x,y): alist.extend((i,j))                              
In [167]: alist                                                                 
Out[167]: [0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
```

`vstack` and `stack` are variations on `concatenate`, adjust the array dimensions in different ways and then joining on different axes.

```
In [169]: np.concatenate((x[:,None], y[:,None]),axis=1)                         
Out[169]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

another way - join the rows, and transpose to columns:

```
In [170]: np.array((x,y)).T                                                     
Out[170]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

yet another way - insert the arrays into a target, specifying an every-other stride:

```
In [171]: res = np.zeros(6,int)                                                 
In [172]: res[::2] = x; res[1::2] = y                                           
In [173]: res                                                                   
Out[173]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5])
```